# how to import json files from fixtures in BDD step definition file in cypress

Tags: cucumber, cypress, bdd

I have the below folder structure in cypress. I am trying to call object repo and test data json files in BDD step definition, but it won't pick the files.

[image: Fixture folder structure]

I have the below functions in command.js file

[image: commands.js file]

Earlier i was calling using the below code in my .cy.js file but the same code is not working with BDD

[image: Script code]

getting bellow error when running
[image: Error while running]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have used `When('login...', () => {` instead of  `When('login...', function() {` since error message says `this` is undefined.

But maybe you already tried that and `When()` does not support Mocha `this` scope (since `When()` is a wrapper over `it()`).

There are alternatives:

- explicitly retrieve the alias value

  ```js
  cy.get('@ORLoginPage').then(RLoginPage => {
    cy.get(RLoginPage.Email...
  ```
- use `require` to get fixtures

  ```js
  const RLoginPage = require('../fixtures/OR_LoginPage.json')

  When('login...', () => {
    cy.get(RLoginPage.Email...
  ```